# Why does my reputation score not appear to display correctly in other sites?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

When looking at my profile in other sites I noticed that my reputation score had an extra ten reputation to what my profile here says. Why does this occur and is there a way to fix it? I also looked at it when logged out and still had the same issue. The other accounts also display fine here.

Comment: What do you mean "other sites"? Can you give an example of what you expect and what you're actually seeing?

Comment: @mattdm Other sites in the SE network and when I expect to see 114 as my reputation score I see 124.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accounts are stored in a denormalized place on our network, meaning they're a slightly outdated copy at times.  In addition to this by-nature lag, there were cases where updates just didn't happen reliably.  A few months ago we put in a system that will notice these discrepancies and fix the denormalized store so the issue corrects itself on-view.

You shouldn't see these types of differences anymore, if you do they'll be gone within 10 minutes (the cache duration).

Answer (score 2):

You actually have multiple accounts for each site within the stack exchange network, and each one has it's own reputation score.

The accounts are linked though, and you get a small reputation bonus for linking your account, so you start higher.

You also have a [network account](https://stackexchange.com/users/1614642/damned-truths?tab=accounts) which you can link to on your user page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it appears to be alright now.